# What "Build project" really do in IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

With fresh project generated by Idea, after "build project" hammer clicked gradle start two tasks

`Executing tasks ':classes :testClasses'...`

I searched but didn't find task/script related to "build project"

Comment: What is unclear in [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#compile_module)?

Comment: Build project probably means to run a predefined set of tasks. Thing is: gradle is a complex thing, so is IntelliJ. Basically you have to first read enough in the gradle user guide to understand the basics of gradle, and then https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html to see what intellij adds.

Comment: I guess Gradle is used for build: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_version_install

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about IDEA much but you should know how java works.

The java compiler compiles your source code `.java` file to an executable `.class` file. This executable file is then run by the Java virtual machine. The IDEA build project should probably compile your code to an executable form.

Refer to [How java works](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ejcarroll/15-100-s05/supps/basics/history.html).